# Get the mininum value from a hash table and assign its key to an object

Tags: arrays, ruby, object, dijkstra

this is a very small piece of code taken from [this book](https://pragprog.com/titles/jwdsal2/a-common-sense-guide-to-data-structures-and-algorithms-second-edition/) about the Dijkstra Algorithm in Ruby: I think I can't post the entire example for copyright issue, so if you want you can download the source code from the above link of the book, the file will be in the folder `jwdsal2-code\code\connecting_everything_with_graphs\dijkstra.rb`. - it runs perfectly and there isn't any error in the code.

The excerpt from the code is the following:

```ruby
    # We visit our next unvisited city. We choose the one that is cheapest
    # to get to from the STARTING city:
    current_city = unvisited_cities.min do |city|
      cheapest_prices_table[city.name]
    end
```

It is very compact construct, and If I fully understand the meaning of it would be:

- for each object, called `city`, within the array `unvisited_cities`
- retrieve the price *value* from the hash table `cheapest_prices_table` where the *key* is the city name. i.e. the string description of the object, retieved using the method `name`
- from all these prices, **take the minimum price**, and the `city` object having that minimum price will be, at last, assigned to `current_city` object.

I have to implement that without using `min`, this is my attempt but without success, I think the problem is that I try erroneously to assign a string to an object:

```ruby
   min_cheapest_price = Float::INFINITY
   min_cheapest_city  = current_city.name
   unvisited_cities.each do |city|
      if cheapest_prices_table[city.name] < min_cheapest_price
         min_cheapest_price = cheapest_prices_table[city.name]
         min_cheapest_city = city.name         
      end
   end
   current_city = min_cheapest_city
```

So, what do you suggest? Many Thanks!

Comment: The only difference I can see between the `min` code and yours is that you assign `min_cheapest_city = city.name ` (a **string**) but the `min` code assigns it to a **city** ... so just remove the `.name` there

Comment: "from all these prices, take the minimum price, and the city object having that minimum price will be, at last, assigned to `current_city` object" — no, this is what `min_by` does. Using `min` with a one-argument block is almost certainly an error.

Comment: @Amadan the statement you quoted, it is what I have understood, so I don't know if correct!. However the original code runs perfectly and there isn't any error in it.

Comment: Sorry for answering late. The error only pops up infrequently, but here is an example: Assume `data = [-2, -1]`. The smallest number is obviously `-2`. Correct: `data.min_by { |x| x }`, `data.min { |a, b| a <=> b }`. However, `data.min { |x| x }` claims the smallest number is `-1`. `min` should always be used with two arguments to be compared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is almost correct.

You assign the `name` of the city to the `current_city` variable whereas the original solution assigns the city object.

```rb
min_cheapest_price = Float::INFINITY
min_cheapest_city  = nil # changed
unvisited_cities.each do |city|
  if cheapest_prices_table[city.name] < min_cheapest_price
    min_cheapest_price = cheapest_prices_table[city.name]
    min_cheapest_city = city # changed         
  end
end
current_city = min_cheapest_city
```

You can simplify it a bit more and remocve the "intermediate" variable `min_current_city`

```rb
min_cheapest_price = Float::INFINITY
current_city = nil
unvisited_cities.each do |city|
  if cheapest_prices_table[city.name] < min_cheapest_price
    min_cheapest_price = cheapest_prices_table[city.name]
    current_city = city         
  end
end
```

Sometimes I try to avoid "magic" values such as `Float::INFINITY` and just use the first item to initialize

```rb
current_city = unvisited_cities.first
minimum_price = cheapest_prices_table[current_city.name] if current_city
unvisited_cities.each do |city|
  current_price = cheapest_prices_table[city.name]
  if current_price < minimum_price
    minimum_price = current_price
    current_city = city
  end
end
```

A bit more code (and theoretically slower) it is sometimes easier to debug, when you have real values right from the beginning.